# Use Woocommerce as a catalog

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I would like to transform WooCommerce plugin to a product catalog by removing cart, prices, shipping .. etc functionalities. (I am using a theme that integrates a page of products (using WooCommerce) for each organisation. )

I am a bit surprised that the plugin itself doesn't offer this option !

I found a paid plugin, but I think that the customization should be easy for people who already used WooCommerce, and that's why I am asking here.

I found that making virtual products will show only a downloadable link, which is some how similar to what I'm trying to have. Is there a setting that allow registred users to publish only this kind of products ?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [Catalog Visibility Options](http://www.woothemes.com/products/catalog-visibility-options/).

Comment: Don't enter any price for the products and use `display:none;` for the add to cart and price on the product page.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove " add to cart " buttons by removing any action hooks that generate this button , you can do this without edit any core code or copying woocommerce files to your theme folder, Just add this code to your functions.php .

```
add_action( 'init', 'catalog_mode', 10 );

function catalog_mode() {

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item'  , 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart'          , 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart'        , 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart'    , 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart'                 , 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart'   , 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart'                , 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart'  , 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart'               , 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart'  , 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart'               , 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation'      , 'woocommerce_single_variation'                   , 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation'      , 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question...but of course you can remove (or, actually, hide) various parts of the platform. All it means is modifying the way your product archives and single products are output. Hide the cart button, and avoid setting up pages for the parts of the plugin you won't be using.

The WooCommerce documentation has [great info on overriding templates](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) to make this possible. The [WooCommerce Codex](http://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/) is also a good place to start.